# Navigation bar color not changing when it is set in the AppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = 0;
    Widget child = FooPage();
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (_, update) {
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => update(() => child = (++count).isEven ? FooPage() : BarPage()),
          ),
          body: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Foo'),
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.black,
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bar'),
        systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
          statusBarColor: Colors.grey,
          systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the status bar color changes but the navigation bar color stays the same. Why is it so? I am testing this on Android.

The two widgets are meant to be used in this way (not through the `Navigator`).

Answer (score 0):

its better put your code in main method above of runApp() and run gain

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black));
```

Comment: Can you please answer how can I do that using the code I shared?