# Status bar color not changing when it is set in the AnnotatedRegion

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int count = 0;
    Widget child = FooPage();
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (_, update) {
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => update(() => child = (++count).isEven ? FooPage() : BarPage()),
          ),
          body: child,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class FooPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.black,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Foo')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.grey,
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bar')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the navigation bar color changes but the status bar color stays the same. Why is it so? I am testing this on Android.

The two widgets are meant to be used in this way (not through the `Navigator`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.orange
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Foo'),systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            statusBarColor: Colors.red,
        )),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: 1st case is not the one for me as I'm using `AppBar`, and in second case, the navigation bar color won't change, [here's the that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72545734/12483095).

Comment: you're completely right ! the only way that you could change the systemNavigationBarColor in AnnotatedRegion widget and the statusBarColor in AppBar widget. It works ^^

Comment: I know this is one of the ways of doing it (which is why I asked two questions on this), but the question is why `AnnotatedRegion` or `AppBar.systemOverlayStyle` alone not doing the complete job?

Comment: Same question ! at the moment we have the only solution above, maybe we could find another way or it will work on the next Flutter version

Answer (score 0):

Use this

---

```
AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.white),
      child: ----
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't make any difference.